# Sort custom listview by natural number

Tags: java, android, sorting

[image]

I want to sort list similar natural number but `Collection.sort()` sorting 1,10,11,12,...,2,20,21,22,..
How to sort similar natural number?

[image: This is my code for sorting]
This is my code for sorting

Comment: How is `Collection.sort()` sorting results as that ? Provide code what you have tried .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use List.sort() in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54192192/1553851)

Comment: @abbas jafary, show the code where you are doing a sorting

Comment: I uploaded my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I understand the issue. You need filters and not sorting to achieve this.
If you are using a RecyclerView you can achieve this as follows

You must have an integer stored in your model file which might look like this.

Model.java

```
public class model {

private String name;
private int no;

public model(String name, int no) {
    this.name = name;
    this.no = no;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNo() {
    return no;
}
}
```

So that you can check if the no is between the span you want it to be. Like this

```
private void filterNaturalNo (ArrayList<model> models){
    ArrayList<model> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (model model: models){
        if (model.getNo() < 5 && model.getNo() > 1){
            filteredList.add(model);
        }
    }
    adapter.refreshAdapter(filteredList);
}
```

This will give you an arrayList with filtered members as you want. Place them in your activity as your requirement. Also if you are using recyclerView this is the `adapter.refreshAdapter(filteredList);` looks like.

```
public void refreshAdapter (ArrayList<model> models){
    modelArrayList = models;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This must work for sure with minor changes. Good luck

Comment: This code is for sorting.I don't think you can achieve what you need like this. Because in sorting you only rearrange the list In the way you want. Your requirement shows that you need to make new filtered list and display that content (which will be set of natural numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your collection is a collection of strings, just map it to ints or create a class-holder with fields "order:Int" and "label: String" and try to sort using the "order" field.